# Making a blank html table cell clickable and return text

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to set up a table where initially all cells are empty, however if a user clicks on a empty cell, text will appear in the cell. Is this possible using only html?

Comment: You shouldn't downvote answers just because you're asking for something that is impossible. It lowers the reputation of users who are trying to help you. This simply isn't possible. Even Chris provided a solution that utilizes CSS beyond HTML. It doesn't even necessarily accomplish what you want. You could do this with JavaScript, a server-side request, or to an extent with CSS, but HTML does not handle interactivity.

Comment: @John-Galt: it is not impossible, I provided an answer using only HTML and CSS, no Javascript at all.

Comment: @Jocelyn: Well, I admit, that was an interesting solution! You can think outside the box, can't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td onclick="this.innerText = 'hello, world'"></td>
```

Keep in mind that the on click value is actually javascript, not purely html.

Answer (score 0):

With HTML and CSS, you can approximate this behavior, but only while the mouse is down.

I am not certain this would work in all browsers, either:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Click the cell:</td>
        <td class="revealer ">
            <div class="revealable">
                MAGIC!!
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The magic happens by (abusing?) the `active` pseudo selector:

```
td.revealer .revealable {
 display:none;   
}
td.revealer:active .revealable {
 display:block;   
}
```

The effect only lasts as long as the mouse is down. On mouse up, the element is no longer "active"

Try it: http://jsfiddle.net/GRMule/awksn/

All that said... the use case for this is pretty narrow. Generally, if you're going to do any kind of dynamic action on your page, you should consider adding a little trivial javascript. Don't get lured in by the big magical libraries though (jQuery, mootools, underscore, etc) -- if all you're doing is a handful of really simple things, you should not add jQuery (for example) just to accomplish this. It is no more or less difficult to do small things like this with plain vanilla javascript than it is with some fancy library, but the library adds 10,000 lines of code you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works using **only** HTML and some CSS:

**Main page**:

```
<html>
<body>
<table border=1>
<tr><td><iframe src="page1.html"></iframe></td><td><iframe src="page1.html"></iframe></td></tr>
<tr><td><iframe src="page1.html"></iframe></td><td><iframe src="page1.html"></iframe></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**page1.html**:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method=post action="page2.html">
<input type="submit" value="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: white; border: none;">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**page2.html**:

```
<html>
<body>
Hello!
</body>
</html>
```

**How it works**:
The main page displays a table. Each cell contains an inline frame.
The content of the inline frame is a form containing a submit button. The submit button has no text and is styled using CSS: white background, no borders, no margins, no padding, 100% width, 100% height. This way it is invisible, and uses the entire table cell.
When you click in the table cell, you actually click the submit button. The form is submitted and displays page2.html (because the form says "action=page2.html")

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not. You could do this with JavaScript, though.

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td onclick="this.innerHTML = 'Data';"></td>
  <td onclick="this.innerHTML = 'Data';"></td>
  <td onclick="this.innerHTML = 'Data';"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td onclick="this.innerHTML = 'Data';"></td>
  <td onclick="this.innerHTML = 'Data';"></td>
  <td onclick="this.innerHTML = 'Data';"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b3hXs/

It would be much better, though, if you did this with jQuery, so you don't have to apply this to each cell. You can download jQuery at jQuery.com and embed it in your page, like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').click(function(){
     $(this).html('Data');
    });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M4RZs/